# Is it possible to create an object without a class in C#?

Tags: c#, object

In many languages you can create an object without creating a data type, and add properties to that object.

For example in JS or AS:

```
 var myObject = {};
 myObject.myParameter = "hello world";
```

Or you can create structures in C and C++.

Is it possible to do that in C#?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes there is `ExpandoObject` under `System.Dynamic` namespace.You could add properties on the fly like you do in other dynamic languages

```
dynamic dynObject = new ExpandoObject();
dynObject.someProperty= "Value";
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx

Answer (score 91):

[Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) is what you looking for. Eg -

```
var v = new { Amount = 108, Message = "Hello" };
```

Above code will create a new `object` with properties `Amount` and `Message`.

Comment: Is this approach better o worse than the expandoobject from the other answers? Why?

Comment: @Pier, this approach is slightly more performant than dynamic as it's actually defining a type at compile time.  There is the preferred approach if you need to organize some data together for local use (such as when performing a LINQ operation that combines data from multiple sources.)  Dynamic is more flexible (you can keep adding fields as you need them), but heavier.

Comment: @Pier They are completely different things. Anonymous classes are determined at compile time. So you can not add/change a property at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for you clarification. ExpandoObject is closer to what I need then, so I will vote any of the two other answers right.

Answer (score 5):

Read about [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx)

```
dynamic myObject = new ExpandoObject();
myObject.myParameter = "hello world";

Console.WriteLine(myObject.myParameter);
```